# Soundcard, blutooth, battery not detected

Tags: sound, battery

I’ve installed Ubuntu 22.10 on my laptop “Samsung Galaxy book S (2020 intel Lakefield)”. There are 3 main problems:
-Soundcard is not detected;
-battery is not detected (can’t find a way to see the battery percentage;
-blutooth is not working.
I’ve seen almost everything that is on AskUbuntu but nothing seem to work… I don’t care a lot about the blutooth, but soundcard is quite important for me. Do you have some advice?[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku3XP.jpg)

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 is not a good choice. It’s out of support and therefore off topic on here. I suggest you try 22.04 or 22.10. Remember 22.10 will only be supported until July 2023 but it’s more likely to support your device out of the box

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a typo. It's actually 22.10